# Как сделать таймеры в C#

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, таймер

Здравствуйте. Передо мной стоит задача - мне необходимо сделать простенькую игру: когда начинаешь игру, через некоторое время необходимо нажать кнопку, и  засечь время реакции игрока, как можно сделать такие таймеры?

Comment: Когда программа сообщает игроку что надо нажать кнопку, сохраняешь время текущее время `DateTime start = DateTime.Now;`
Когда игрок нажимает кнопку, высчитываешь разницу `TimeSpan stop = DateTime.Now - start;`

Comment: @WebMorda: Ну вы бы опубликовали в виде ответа, а?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего для этого использовать `Stopwatch`. Подключить надо `System.Diagnostics`.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

// Тут какой-то код

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
// также можно использовать sw.ElapsedTicks
```

[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)